# Run same Oozie job multiple times in parallel, with different values in argument for each job

Tags: java, oozie

I want to run a program that converts given input file to another format. 
When a file is uploaded to input table, oozie scheduler should start the job.

For single file it is working fine; If input table have multiple entries at same time, same number of jobs should start parallely with different **inputPath** in arguments. 
Oozie workflow takes "InputPath" and "OutputPath" as argument.

How can I do this?

Comment: *How can I do this?* - maybe java code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question in this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to trigger jobs based on *events*. Oozie was not designed for that, it just runs *scheduled*  jobs based on a time table (w/ optionally a deferred start until arrival of specific files).

Consider other options, e.g. AirFlow or Luigi.